# Html form tag autocomplete="off" attribute not working on chrome browser

Tags: php, html, css

I have user registration form. Form contains username and password field.
At the time of user registration username and password fields automatically populated values.

I have used form "autocomplete" attribute, but not working on chrome browser.

This is my code,

```
<form method="post" action=""  autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
<input type="text" id="username_name" name="username_name">
<input type="text" id="password" name="password">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, Chrome only autocompletes the first `<input type="password">` and the previous . So I added:

```
<input style="display:none">
<input type="password" style="display:none">
```

To the top of the `<form>` and the case was resolved.

Comment: omg i've seen lots of css and js hacks for this! by far the easiest